# Show Hide Table Row based on Check Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Seenu/pbtbS/) I am trying to show/hide table row containing File input based on Check Box selection. But the showHide function is not getting called.

```
<div align="center" class="divBody">
<br />
<div id="controlHost">
    <div id="outerPanel">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
            <tr align="left">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" onclick="showHide()">only Textbox</input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left" id="fileLabel">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="message" >Select file</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left" id="fileBox">
                <td valign="top" style="height:100%; width:70%;">
                    <input type="file" id="FileInput" multiple="false" class="fileInput" style="height:100%; width:100%;"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
         <tr align="left">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="message" >Types</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtTypes" tabindex="0" style="margin-left:1px;width:100%" maxlength="50" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="button" id="upload" name="Upload" value="Update" onclick="startUpload('FileInput', 1048576, 'uploadProgress', 'statusMessage', 'upload', 'cancel');"
                        class="button" />
                    <input type="button" id="cancel" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" disabled="disabled"
                        onclick="cancelUpload();" class="button" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There may be some issue. But the same code if I run on my local vs then it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you code itself it is clear that *you're missing jQuery library*(in fiddle, I dont see the library included).

```
document.getElementById('fileLabel').show();
```

in jQuery you can simplify this as

```
$('#fileLabel').show();
```

**`.show()/.hide()`** are jQuery methods.

like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#c1').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('#filelabel').show();
            $('#fileBox').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#filelabel').hide();
            $('#fileBox').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in the fiddle

1. Select No Wrap head/body in the second dropdown in the left panel - when `onload` is selected your script is added with in a `window.onload = function(){//your code}` wrapper making the function local to the wrapper function.
2. You need to include jQuery library in the page
3. Methods like `show()/hide()` are bound to jQuery wrapper object

   only Textbox

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#c1').change(function () {
        $('#fileLabel, #fileBox').toggle(this.checked)
    }).change()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5hnSv/)

Answer (score 0):

The function is work please write javascript in head section of html

```
<head>
<script>
function showHide() {
    alert('called');
    var chbox = document.getElementById("c1");
    var vis = "none";
    for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) { 
        if(chbox.checked){
            alert('checked');
            document.getElementById('fileLabel').show();
            document.getElementById('fileBox').show();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('unchecked');
            document.getElementById('fileLabel').hide();
            document.getElementById('fileBox').hide();
            break;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Left panel **Framework and Extensions** >> Second Drop down set **No wrap - in**

It will start working.